# How can I pass ENV value in Dockerfile from .env file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My directory structure looks like this.

|
|
--- Dockerfile
| --- .env

Content of `.env` file looks like this.

```
VERSION=1.2.0
DATE=2022-05-10
```

I want to access `VERSION` and `DATE` as environment variable both during **build time** and **run time**. So `ENV` is the one I should use. I know that.
How exactly can I do that ?

I tried using `RUN` command in `Dockerfile` like

```
RUN export $(cat .env)
```

But, it can only be accessed during runtime and not build time.
So, how can this be achieved with `ENV` ?

I can do it manually like

```
ENV VERSION 1.2.0
ENV DATE 2022-05-10
```

But, it is inefficient when I have many environment variables.

P.S. I cannot use `docker-compose` because the image is going to be used by kubernetes pods, so.

Comment: Dockerfiles support ARG or ENV variables.  .ENV files and the variables they provide are only used by the the docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could firstly export these variables as environmetal variables to your bash

```
source .env
```

Then use `--build-arg` flag to pass them to your docker build

```
docker image build --build-arg VERSION=$VERSION --build-arg DATE=$DATE .
```

Next in your dockerfile

```
ARG VERSION
ARG DATE
ENV version=$VERSION
ENV date=$DATE
```

As a result, for example you can access the variables in your build phase as `VERSION` and in your container as `version`

Answer (score 0):

What I've read from others says that there is no "docker build --env-file...." option/apparatus.  As such, this situation makes a good argument for shifting more of the content of the dockerfile to a shell script that the dockerfile simply copies and runs, as you can source the .env file that way.

greetings.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

source variables.env
echo Foo $copyFileTest
```

variables.env

```
export copyFileTest="Bar"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY variables.env .
RUN source variables.env && echo Foo $copyFileTest  #outputs: Foo Bar
COPY greetings.sh .
RUN chmod +x /greetings.sh
RUN /greetings.sh               #outputs: Foo Bar

RUN echo $copyFileTest          #does not work, outputs nothing
```

Answer (score -3):

You can specify the `env_file` in the `docker-compose.dev.yml` file as follows:

```
# docker-compose.dev.yml

services:
  app:
    ...
    env_file:
        - .env.development
```

and you have to have a .env.development file containing all the environment variables you need to pass to the docker image.

e.g.:

```
# .env.development

REACT_APP_API_URL="https://some-api-url.com/api/graphql"
```

Comment: The context is building the image, not docker-compose.